# Symfony2: deleted property still used in query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, apc, query-builder, doctrine-query

I deleted a property (teaser) from an enitiy (sale).
I used the CLi to update the database & entites:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --complete --force
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Our --no-backup
$ php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
$ php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

And i cleared the cache:

```
$ php app/console cache:clear --no-optional-warmers --no-warmup
```

Now i have a query created by query builder:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
$q = $qb
    ->select('s.id')
    ->leftJoin('s.bills','b')
    ->where('b.paid = true')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

This throws an error becuas eit generates a select statement that includes the old property:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 's0_.teaser' in 'field list'
```

I tried to understand how Doctrine executes the query but failed to find the source of the problem.
Does anyone have any clues?

**UPDATE:** I took the DQL from the query, generated by the querybuilder and then used that to create a new Query. Same Error. Then i changed one word in the DQL from uppercae to lowercase (*LEFT* is now *Left*) and that one executed just fine.

```
$q = $this->getEntityManager()
->createQuery('SELECT s,b FROM Our\BuyBundle\Entity\Sale s Left JOIN s.bills b WHERE s.id IN (:randomIds)')
->setParameter('randomIds', $allSaleIds);
```

So it seems the DQL Statement is cached somewhere, Using the DQL as a hash to get the corresponding SQL Statement.
I still can't quite figure out where and how to clear that cached Information. Especially given the fact that i deleted all content in the app/cache folder as well.

UPDATE2: Found the Solution. Had to clear the APC Cache manually since the console can't do that.
So the Solution would be:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
```

And if that doesn't work, clear your APC Cache.

Comment: did you run `app/console cache:clear --evn=prod`? Also try `rm -rf app/cache/*`

Comment: yes, i cleared the cache for all environments. i get the error with all querybuilder querys using that entity.

Comment: are you sure that is the query with the problem? try searching in all project `s.teaser` who knows...

Comment: @alex.dominte: Yes, i am sure. See the Update. Also i found the Solution now. Thanks for the help thou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Problem was the APC Cache.

I could not clear the *query-cache* in CLI (*app/console*) since the console can't (*or is not allowed to*) clear the APC Cache.
So i had to clear the APC Cache manually.

Solution is:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

And if that doesn't work, **clear the APC Cache** (*or whatever cache you use*) manually.